# How to remove the filters and store the unique values in another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having a column called course in my table which as rows lyk

```
row1 : course:1|course:2|course:3
row2 : Course:2|course:4|NUll
```

now i have to eliminate the filter '|' in the rows and store the distinct value in another table .. how ll i do it..??
 using SP

I'm excepting the output column to be like :

```
Course:1
Course:2
Course:3
Course:4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table table1(A varchar(50),B varchar(50),C varchar(50));

insert into table1 values('course:1','course:2','course:3');
insert into table1 values('course:2','course:4',null);
```

**SQL Query**

```
Select Distinct value
From table1
unpivot
(
  value
  For Cource in (A, B, C)
) U;
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43530/2)**

**Output:**

---

```
  +-----------+
  |  VALUE    |
  +-----------+
  | course:1  |
  | course:2  |
  | course:3  |
  | course:4  |
  +-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function to split row value, look at this [link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/07/sql-server-split-function-example-in.html)

Then if your data like this:

```
create table table1 (course varchar(1000))
insert into table1 ( course) values ('course:1|course:2|course:3'),('course:2|course:4|NULL')
```

This query using function to split string, and you can put this code into Stored Procedure

```
select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by course)as Number,* 
into #temp
from table1

declare @flag int, @count int
select @count=COUNT(''), @flag=1 from table1

create table #result(items varchar(100))
while @flag<=@count
begin
    declare @row varchar(1000)
    select @row=course from #temp where Number=@flag
    insert into #result
    select Items from [dbo].[Split](@row,'|')
    where Items<>'NULL'
    set @flag=@flag+1
end

select distinct * from #result

drop table #result
drop table #temp
```

Output:

```
+---------+
|Items    |
+---------+
|course:1 |
|course:2 |
|course:3 |
|course:4 |
+---------+
```